# searching english and japanese with solr

Tags: solr, lucene, full-text-search, multilingual, solrj

We have a customer that needs support for both english and japanese, a document can be any of the two and we have no indication about the language for a document. ,so I know I can construct a schema with both english and japanese fields and index them with copy field. we are using the standard request handler not dismax and we want to keep using it as our queries should be on certain fields with no errors.
queries are user entered and can be any valid query like q=lexmark or q=docname:lexmark AND content:printer , now what I think I want is to add the japanese fields to this query and end up with q=docname:lexmark OR docname_ja:lexmark. of course I can not ask the use to do that. the values can be japanese or english. and also we have only one default field and it must be japanese or english but not both. I think the default field can be solved by using dixmax and specify multi default fields with qt, but we don't use dismax.
we use solrj as our client and It would be better if I could do something in the client side and not in solr side.

any help/idea is appreciated. ?

Answer (score 0):

You can check for the [Language Detection](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/LanguageDetection) feature wich will enable language detection and indexing of the fields accordingly.

Comment: Thanks. so I can detect language when indexing and index in japanese or english. but i need the same thing for search and I can't find a way to do it. as i said its user entered queries, user enters a query like docname:lexmark.